# Nav Drawer Menu Android - Group of items listview

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to do a navigator drawer menu in android and until now I did it:
[image]

But I want like a group of items like this edited image on paint:
[image]

How can I do it?
How can divide some items?

Thanks!

Edit:

navigation_drawer_base_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_list"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

BaseActivity.java

```
package br.com.tokendev.mymoney;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to navigation drawer.
 * We are going to extend all our other activites from this BaseActivity so that every activity will have Navigation Drawer in it.
 * This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.   
 */
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/**
 *  Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
 *  This layout is protected so that child activity can access this 
 *  */
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

/**
 * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
 * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened. 
 */

protected ListView mDrawerList;

/**
 * List item array for navigation drawer items.
 * */
protected String[] listArray;
protected String[] listIconArray;

/**
 * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list. 
 * */
protected static int position;

/**
 *  Base layout node of this Activity.   
 * */
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

/**
 * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

private Context mContext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

    mContext = this;

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_list);

    listArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_list);
    listIconArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_list_icon);
    ArrayList<NavDrawerMenu> listMenu = new ArrayList<NavDrawerMenu>();
    for (int i=0; i<listArray.length; i++) {
        listMenu.add(new NavDrawerMenu(listArray[i],getResources().getIdentifier(listIconArray[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName())));
    }

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    ListViewDrawerMenu adapter = new ListViewDrawerMenu(mContext,
            R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout, listMenu);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    //mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            openActivity(position);
        }
    });

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                       /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.app_name,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.app_name)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };

    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * @param position
 *
 * Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
 */
protected void openActivity(int position) {

    /**
     * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
     * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
     * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
     * So that we are setting this in child activity.   
     */

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    if (position == BaseActivity.position) return;

    if (BaseActivity.position != 0) finish();

    BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        BaseActivity.position = 0;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use 3 different list and add a footer for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with three listviews or with just one list containing `null` values at positions where separators must placed:

1. Use two layouts: one for item and another for separator.
2. Create an adapter with an items list as parameter in constructor as usual.
3. In the list you'll pass set the items you want to be separators to `null`.
4. In adapter, implement on `getView`, where you check if the current item is `null`, to create a separator, or not, to create a regular item.

Comment: How can I do it? have same example?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you already have. I'll try to show you how to transform it into what you want to do.

Comment: You must implement a custom adapter and replace the ArrayAdapter you are using.